# how to configure the database in meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, authentication, meteor

I thought that [meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) stored its data in a mongo database, but when I check my local mongo database nothing is in there. How does this work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meteor is using its own copy of mongodb database and you can access it by running

```
$ meteor mongo
```

in the project root directory.

The database files are located within the hidden `.meteor` directory.

You can also use your local mongodb client to connect to meteor's copy through `localhost:3001` if you are using a recent meteor version (>=0.7.x)

If you want to bypass using meteor's mongodb and use your own, you can do that by setting the `MONGO_URL` environment variable like

```
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/your-db-name
```